# Guessing number using lower,higher,correct options in java

Tags: java, loops, range

I'm trying to write a java code in java that has following output.

> ```
> ---JGRASP exez: java Guess
>     Is the number 50? H
>     Ia the number 75? L
>     Is the number 62? L
>     Is the number 56? L
>     Is the number 53? L
>     Is the number 51? C
>     It took me 6 guesses!
>   ---JGRASP: operation complete.
> ```

As you see it always cuts range in half.I spent hours trying to figure it out without results.I would really appreciate if you could at least give a hint.Here's my unsuccessful attempt to write the code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class GuessNumber
{
   public static void main(String[]args)
   {
          int num1 = 0,num2 = 100,guesses = 0;
          String answer;
          boolean correct = false;

          Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

          do{
              System.out.print("Is the number " + <?> + "? ");       //have no idea
              answer = keyboard.next();

              if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("C")) {
                    correct = true;
                    guessses++;
               }  
              else if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("H")){
                    ? = (num1 + num2) / 2;                   //lost here 
                    guesses++;
               } 
              else if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("L")){
                    ? = (num1 + num2) / 2;                   //lost here
                    guesses++;
               }
           }while(correct == false);

    System.out.print("It took me " + guesses + " guesses!");   
 }
```

}

Comment: btw guessing range is between 1-100

Comment: How about having a variable `int currentGuess` that holds, uhm, I don't know, the current guess the computer is making? Then start reassigning its value where you wrote `?` in your code...

Comment: I guess for start, you do not want the answer to be input on every loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[]args)
{
          Random randomNumber = new Random();
          int num1 = 0,num2 = 100,guesses = 0, guess=0;
          String answer;
          boolean correct = false;

          Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

          do{
              guess=randomNumber.nextInt(num2-num1) + num1; 

              System.out.print("Is the number " + guess + "? ");       
              answer = keyboard.next();

              if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("C")) {
                    correct = true;
                    guessses++;
               }  
              else if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("H")){
                    num1 = guess;              
                    guesses++;
               } 
              else if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("L")){
                    num2 = guess;                  
                    guesses++;
               }
           }while(correct == false);    
           System.out.print("It took me " + guesses + " guesses!");   
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, what it does is that, while the answer is not correct, It will take in num1(the min value for the guess) and num2(the max value for the guess) and find their average. If the number is higher than the latest guess, we set the lower bound to the latest guess, if it's lower, we set the upper bound to the latest guess.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GuessNumber{

public static void main(String[]args)
{
          int num1 = 0,num2 = 101,guesses = 0, guess=0;
          String answer;
          boolean correct = false;

          Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
          do{
              guess=(num1+num2) /2 > 0? (num1+num2) /2:1;

              System.out.print("Is the number " + guess + "? ");       
              answer = keyboard.next();

              if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("C")) {
                    correct = true;
                    guesses++;
               }  
              else if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("H")){
                    num1 = guess;              
                    guesses++;
               } 
              else if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("L")){
                    num2 = guess;                  
                    guesses++;
               }

           }while(correct == false);    
           System.out.print("It took me " + guesses + " guesses!");   
 }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.I was so close but never got there.

Comment: Thanks Kevin.You saved me hours.